# Button event doesn't raise selected event on UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, xcode5, uicollectionview

I have got a UICollectionView where I handle clicks on cells using `UICollectionViewDelegate` methods `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`/ `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath`.

The problem is I have added some buttons to the cell and they don't fire the select/ deselect methods.

I have actually already fixed this problem with a complicated solution (I delegate my button events to the `collectionviewcontroller` and maintain my own list of selected cells), but it's pretty complicated and I sense it could be refactored to make it a lot simpler.

Any ideas on how you can click a button on a `UICollectionViewCell` and still fire a `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`/ `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` methods on the `collectionviewcontroller`?